# Bulk Import XML into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was looking at these examples on Microsoft.com here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225754%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

But it's saying in part of it's steps that VBScript code has to be executed, and I wasn't able to find where the VBScript should be executed.  Is it possible to be executed in SQL Server itself?

The code from the site looks something like this:

```
 Set objBL = CreateObject("SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkLoad")
 objBL.ConnectionString = "provider=SQLOLEDB.1;data source=MySQLServer;
                           database=MyDatabase;uid=MyAccount;pwd=MyPassword"
 objBL.ErrorLogFile = "c:\error.log"
 objBL.Execute "c:\customermapping.xml", "c:\customers.xml"
 Set objBL = Nothing
```

This looks like it could be executed in classic asp or something, but I prefer to keep it inside SQL Server.  Does anyone know how to execute something like this all with-in SQL Server?  or does anyone have a better method for Bulk import XML into SQL server?

Comment: You could use VB6, Visual Basic for Applications IDE from Office (Word, Excel, PP, etc. : Alt + F11 > Insert > Module > `Sub Test()\n ... source code .. \nEnd Sub`) or VbsEdit.

Comment: VBScript? Why are you starting from 7-year old KB articles and SQL Server 2000 documentation? Why wouldn't you start at [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184(v=sql.100).aspx), which is much more recent, geared to the platform you're actually on, and took about 20 seconds to locate as the top hit via a search for "bulk import XML into SQL Server", the last sentence in your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQL Server is capable of reading XML and inserting it as you need. Here is an example of an XML file and insertion pulled from [here](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/11/import-xml-file-to-sql-table.html):

XML:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <SKU>1</SKU>
    <Desc>Book</Desc>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <SKU>2</SKU>
    <Desc>DVD</Desc>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <SKU>3</SKU>
    <Desc>Video</Desc>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Insert statement that is parsing the XML:

```
INSERT INTO Products (sku, product_desc) 
SELECT X.product.query('SKU').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.product.query('Desc').value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'C:\Products.xml',
     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
     ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Products/Product') AS X(product);
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very helpful. But how about for attributes like `<product id="123">` ?

Comment: Nevermind, found it here.. http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/06/shredding-xml-in-sql-server-2005.html  Will look at this solution and try to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: I am wondering how this compares with csv/bcp in performance. Say for a file size of a few GB.

Comment: FWIW - In my situation, this process seemed exceptional slow and CPU intensive.  I found a faster, SQL-only approach below.

Answer (score 6):

I tried this and for 975 rows from a 1MB XML file, this took about 2.5 minutes to execute on a very fast PC.

I switched to using OpenXml in a multi-step process and process takes less than a second.

```
CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    XMLData XML,
    LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)    

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'clients.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;



DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)    

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML WHERE ID = '1' -- The row to process    

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML


INSERT INTO Clients
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Clients/Client')
WITH 
(
    CustomerID [varchar](50) 'ID',
    CustomerName [varchar](100) 'Name'
)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

I got this from here:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/

Basically you load the XML into a table as a big blob of text, then you use OpenXml to process it.

Comment: this worked for me - @Ocelot20 version took 56 mins to process my own XML file whereas this version took a few seconds.